# Check Privilege Level for .exe files

Tags: windows, vbscript, windows-7, exe, batch-processing

I've an application to deploy on ~300 Windows 7 computers.
I don't have a setup to install this app, just need to copy/paste in program files directory.

In the binaries dir, I've 9 executable files.
For each .exe, I need to check the box : "Run this program as an administrator" for all users. I've the local admin credentials.

My need is the do that in batch or VBScript or Regedit or any language (Python, C/C++, Java, others...) but NOT in AutoIt / AutoHotkey.

Can you help me to find the solution?

[image: Run this program as an administrator]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to do by setting a simple registry key. In this case, use [`REG.exe`](https://ss64.com/nt/reg.html)'s `ADD` option to set this registry value via a batch file.

**Command: `REG ADD [ROOT\]RegKey /v ValueName [/t DataType] [/S Separator] [/d Data] [/f]`**

*For current user only:*

```
REG ADD "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers" /v << 'FULL (DOUBLE QUOTED) PATH TO YOUR APPLICATION'S EXECUTABLE FILE >> /d "RUNASADMIN"
```

*For all users:*

```
REG ADD "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers" /v << 'FULL (DOUBLE QUOTED) PATH TO YOUR APPLICATION'S EXECUTABLE FILE >> /d "RUNASADMIN"
```

Example (for all users):

```
REG ADD "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers" /v "C:\My Program\MyProgram.exe" /d "RUNASADMIN"
```

If you want to set this for all users, you should run your batch file with administrator privileges.

Comment: That's work, you just forget to remove the << symbols on your examples.

Comment: @locobastos Sorry, my mistake. Fixed it. Thanks for remembering. :-)